# How to put a local database onto a server?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql(v5) database running on my computer in college,

how do i go about placing this database onto a server?

if there is a way to export the schema and recreate the database that would be handy.

if i could put all the information from the database that would be a plus,

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dump the database into a file:

`mysqldump -u username -p dbname > dbname.sql`

now import the sql file using:

`mysql -u username dbname < dbname.sql`

make sure to place username with the actual username, maybe root for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Log into phpMyAdmin and select the DB you want to export. Click on the export tab on the top and make sure "Save as File" is checked towards the bottom. This will allow you to save the entire schema and contents of the DB. You can then import the data by using the import tab and selecting the file you saved.